# Unable to mount DEVICE Android

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, samsung-mobile, drivers

I used to use those devices before over months on windows and ubuntu and had not encountered such a problem. Now it occurs very often. May it be connected with any libraries, or privileges? This does not occur every time.

I use `ubuntu 14.04 x64 and device is sgs2(android 4.1.2).`

[image]

Appreciate any ideas.